# running time of t(n) = t(n-2) + (n-2)²

Tags: algorithm, big-o

can anyone tell me if the following solution is correct?

I am trying to calculate the running time of **t(n) = t(n-2) + (n-2)²**

evaluating it further

**=> t(n)=t(n-4) + (n-2)² + n²**

**=> t(n)=t(n-6) + (n-6)² + (n-2)² + n²**

...since it is reducing by 2 it would have around n/2 terms and by expanding all the squares
we have (n/2) * (n²) which is equal to n³.So the the running time is **theta(n³)**

is this the correct solution?

Comment: This is more of a computerscience.stackexchange.com question.

Comment: You want to calculate the running time of that function? I.e. you want to know what the running time would be if you implemented that function as a computer program? Or do you mean that function *is* your running time and you want to know which O it's in?

Comment: yes i want to calculate the running time of the function (order of the function)

Comment: @Sid I don't think you got my point. If you implement your function as a computer program, its running time will be `Theta(n)` (or `Theta(n log n)` if you use bignums), but I'm not sure whether that's what you wanted to know.

Comment: @sepp2k I wanted to verify if I solved the problem correctly.I was solving some problems in CLRS introduction to algorithms.Sorry should have written that.
Thanks for letting me know about bignums though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the above is perfectly correct (with the small exception of the first line should be `t(n) = t(n-4) + (n-4)^2 + (n-2)^2` according to the problem definition, and correcting what follows - but it does not affect the asymptotical outcome).

To prove this, we can use [mathematical induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction):

```
Claim: t(n) <= n^3
base: T(2) = 2 (assumption - otherwise we'll get stuck)
let's assume the assumption is true for each n<k for a certain k.
t(k) = t(k-2) + (k-2)^2 <= (k-2)^3 + (k-2)^2 = 
     = k^3 -6k^2 + 12k -8 + k^2 - 4k + 4
     = k^3 -5k^2 + 8k - 4
```

All is left is to show that [`5k^2 >= 8k - 4`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5k%5E2%20%2b4%20%3E%208k%20) and we are done. The equation holds for each `k>=2` - proving it is left as an exrecise.

From the above we can derive t(n) is in `O(n^3)`. Using similar approach we can show it is also in `Omega(n^3)`, and thus it is `Theta(n^3)`

Comment: I made a minor calculation mistake: `k^3 -5k^2 + 8k + 4` should actually be `k^3 -5k^2 + 8k - 4` - it does not change the end conclusion of course, the formula will still be true for each k >= 2.

Answer (score 2):

[Using this online calculator](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%20t%28n%29%20=%20t%28n-2%29%20%2b%20%28n-2%29%5E2&dataset=) you can see Θ(n^3) as a result.

[image: n^3]

Right multiplication creates Θ(n^3), as I think.

Comment: Where do you see that? Do you need the pro-version to get asymototic running time?

Comment: @TheUnfunCat look at post update